# mac OS microphone only works when System Preferences Dictation pane is open

Tags: mac, audio, microphone, sound-volume

When using my Mac on various apps (Zoom, Quicktime audio recorder, Skype etc.), the input from all microphones is extremely quiet and voices become inaudible.

This occurs for the inbuilt microphone, for Bluetooth headphones, and for AUX headphones.

The input volume is turned up to max (see pic below)

[image]

But very strangely, when I open the Dictation Preference Pane (pic below), the microphone then works normally in all apps.

[image: Dictation Preference Pane]

Anyone have any ideas why this might be occuring? And how I can fix it so that the microphone input works normally all the time?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem a year ago on a Macbook A1708 and no solution other than dictation worked. Today my patience snapped, I contacted Apple support and continued to look for a way out of the situation without waiting for an answer. After 6 hours I decided to just brush the right mesh of the case with a toothbrush and it was the right decision. Now the microphone works like new. Why did this happen (theory): there are two microphones in the macbook, the main one is clogged, and when you turn on dictation or Siri, the SECOND MICROPHONE turns on.

Sorry for bad english, I'm Russian.